# Fixing upsert issue with TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions, isolation-level

I have a SQL statement that does an update, and then if the `@@ROWCOUNT` is 0, it will insert.  this is basically a `MERGE` in SQL 2008.  We are running into situations where two threads are failing on the update simultaneously.  It will attempt to insert the same key twice in a table.  We are using the Default Transaction isolation level, Read Committed.  Will changing the level to repeatable reads fix this or do I have to go all the way to Serializable to make this work?  Here is some code:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

BEGIN TRAN;                                            
UPDATE TableA
SET Duration = @duration              
WHERE keyA = @ID
AND keyB = @IDB;

IF @@rowcount = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TableA (keyA,keyB,Duration) 
VALUES (@ID,@IDB,@duration); 

END
COMMIT TRAN;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;";
```

Comment: You don't get dirty reads with the Read Committed Transaction Isolation level. You can only get dirty reads with Read Uncommitted.

Comment: Sorry meant to say  - making the update and the insert atomic.  How do I combine them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to go all the way up to `SERIALIZABLE`.

Under `REPEATABLE READ` if the row does not exist then both `UPDATE` statements can run concurrently without blocking each other and proceed to do the insert. Under  `SERIALIZABLE` the range where the row would have been is blocked.

But you should also consider leaving the isolation level at default `read committed` and putting a unique constraint on `keyA,keyB` so any attempts to insert a dupe fail with an error.